# set datasource for combobox

Tags: jquery

how to set datasoure of combobox by jquery

`data={"a","b","c","d"}`. and `ComboBox.datasource=data;`==>by jquery

Comment: Please add some more information

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this
using this plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/combobox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
            var options;


            $.each(data, function(i, item ) { 
                options += "<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>";
            });

            $("#combobox").append(options).combobox();
 });

<select id="combobox"></select>
```